# throw Exception order

Tags: java, iterator

Why does it matter if I put throw new NoSuchElementException(); after new ConcurrentModificationException();

```
public E next() {
            if (hasNext()) {
                if (_expectedModCount == _modCount) {
                    return _store[_cursor++];
                }
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();

            }
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();


        }
    }
```

when I put concurrentModificationException before NoSuchElement exception my Junit tests say it fails a test why is that? But when I wrote it the way I have it in the code it passes all tests
or is that just the way the prof wrote tests?

Comment: @ScaryWombat it can be reached

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh Embarrassingly so.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "put ... before"? Please show the alternative code.